# cumsum when current obs equals next obs for same variable (column)

Tags: r

I want to add a column to a dataframe that makes a cumulated sum of another variable if yet another variable is equal for two rows. For example:

```
  Row   Var1    Var2    CumVal
  1 A 2 2
  2 A 4 6
  3 B 5 5
```

So I want `CumVal` to cumulate/sum the `Var2` column, if `Var1` obs for row 2 equals `Var1` obs for row 1. With other words, if it is equal to the obs before.

Comment: Suppose if the 4th row for `Var1` is `A`, could you show the output?

Answer (score 1):

If the `cumsum` is based on the `Var1` as a grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(Var1) %>% 
    mutate(CumVal=cumsum(Var2))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, CumVal:=cumsum(Var2), by=Var1]
```

Or using `base R`

```
transform(df, CumVal=ave(Var2, Var1, FUN=cumsum))
```

#### Update

If it is based on whether adjacent elements are not equal

```
transform(df, CumVal= ave(Var2, cumsum(c(TRUE,Var1[-1]!= 
                                  Var1[-nrow(df)])), FUN=cumsum))

#    Row Var1 Var2 CumVal
#1   1    A    2      2
#2   2    A    4      6
#3   3    B    5      5
#4   4    A    6      6
```

Or the `dplyr` approach

```
df %>% 
   group_by(indx= cumsum(c(TRUE,(lag(Var1)!=Var1)[-1]))) %>%
   mutate(CumVal=cumsum(Var2)) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(-indx)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Row = 1:4, Var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "A"), Var2 = c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("Row", "Var1", "Var2"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `rle`, which detects similar successive values in a vector and describe it in a nice synthetic way. E.g. let's say we have a vector `x` of length 10:

```
x <- c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1)
```

`rle` is able to detect that there are 4 successive 2s and 2 successive 0s:

```
rle(x)

# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:6] 1 1 4 2 1 1
#   values : num [1:6] 2 3 2 0 2 1
```

(in the output, we can that there are 2 lengths different from 1 corresponding to values 4 and 2)

We can use this function to apply `cumsum` to subvectors of another vector. Let's say we want to apply `cumcum` on a new vector `y <- 1:10`, but only for repeated values of `x` (which will be stored in a factor `f`):

```
y <- 1:10
z <- rle(x)$lengths
f <- factor(rep( seq_along(z), z) )
```

We can then use `by` or `tapply` (or something else to achieve the desired output):

```
cumval <- unlist(tapply(y, f, cumsum))
```